# Yii Framework 2.0 Relational Database Active Record

Tags: php, yii, relational-database, one-to-many, yii2

I am working with Yii framework 2.0 and have two database tables (A and B). It is a relational database 1:n. A has only one B but B has many of A. My database looks similar to this.

```
A table:
id = 1, name = yes
id = 2, name = no
id = 3, name = ok
id = 4, name = good

B table:
id = 1, a_id = 1
id = 2, a_id = 1
id = 3, a_id = 2
id = 4, a_id = 2
id = 5, a_id = 3
```

In my controller I use the following code to retrieve all data of A and B:

```
$bModel = B::find()->all();
```

In my view I use the following for-each to echo all the data.

```
foreach($bModel as $b) {
   echo $b->a->name . ' - ' $b->id. '<br>;
}
```

The result is:

```
 yes - 1
 yes - 2
 no  - 3
 no  - 4
```

What I want is:

```
 yes - 1  
       2

 no - 3
      4
```

I want to merge the a_id and show all the b's id of each merged a_id. I don't want to use the normal way by firstly get all a's id, use for-each to loop each a's id and then query b one by one by a's id. How can I approach the second result as I wanted with Yii framework 2.0?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the joinWith() method to eagerly load related models.  Eager Loading will fetch all B relations with one query, so that you aren't querying the database each time in the loop.  First, ensure that you have this relation defined in model A:

```
/**
 * @return \yii\db\ActiveQuery
 */
public function getBs()
{
    return $this->hasMany(A::className(), ['a_id' => 'id']);
}
```

Next, query all of the records together by using the joinWith() method:

```
foreach (A::find()->joinWith('bs')->all() as $a){
    echo $a->name."\n<br />\n";
    foreach ($a->bs as $relatedB){
        echo $relatedB->name.' - '.$relatedB->id."\n<br />\n";
    }
    echo "\n<br />\n";
}
```

joinWith() defaults to Eager Loading joined models using LEFT JOIN.  If you run this query and enable database logging, you should only see one query to fetch the A models and one query to fetch the B models.

More about joining with relations: http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-db-active-record.html#joining-with-relations

Comment: In case there is id=3 in the A table but there is NO a_id=3 in the B table and I want to query only the A records which B has it's a_id as foreign key. How can I do that?

Comment: I think what you are describing is an Inner Join.  In that case, try changing the code in the foreach loop from `A::find()->joinWith('bs')->all()` to `A::find()->innerJoinWith('bs')->all()`

Comment: It works great. Thanks for that. Unfortunately I also need to use the pagination widget. So I used you latter code like this: A::find()->innerJoinWith('bs'); And my pagination code goes like this: $pagination = new Pagination([
                'defaultPageSize' => 2,
                'totalCount'      => A->count(),
            ]);
        
$allA = A->offset($pagination->offset)->limit($pagination->limit)->all();

Comment: In the view, it turns out that the pagination numbers come from the division of ALL the B records divided by 2 which is 3 pagination numbers considered the sample database above. Because there are only three a_id's (1,2,3) in the B table. The result is now, page:1, a_id:1 -> b:1, b:2 / page:2, a_id:2 -> b:3, b:4 and a_id:3 -> b:5 / page:3, a_id:3 -> b:5. This is the result of using pagination widget in combination with your innerJoinWith().

Comment: it means that the first page has only one A with two B records, besides that, a_id = 3 is present in both the second and the third page. Hope you can follow me and my issue and can help.

Comment: I have added my new question related to this but with a better issue explanation: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26905245/yii-framework-2-0-join-two-relational-database-tables-and-using-pagination-widge